# Template debug areas on transaction emails

Tags: magento2, email-templates, debugging

We are sending out order confirmation emails programatically using the following code in Magento 2:

```
# Now send out the emails:
$emailSender = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender');
$emailSender->send($order);
```

All of the information is pulling through correctly on the email (and the order is being placed in Magento backend), but when the mail is delivered, it appears as though the template has debug hints on it, despite all template debug options being disabled in the Store config:

[image]

What is the reason for this, and how can we disable the red areas on the email template?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a transactional email template using the [Postcards](https://designmodo.com/postcards/). I hope this resource will be helpful.

Also, you can download free email templates from [GitHub](https://github.com/designmodo/html-email-templates).